# Getting decimals from a String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read ALL decimals from a String in Haskell, I currently have the following function:

```
readDecimals :: String -> [Int]
readDecimals n = (n - fromIntegral(floor n))
```

The problem is that this function doesn't work with a String, can anyone help me here?

Comment: There is no implicit type conversion in Haskell, you have to convert everything explicitly.  Have you looked at the `read` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Data.Char

readDecimals :: String -> [Int]
readDecimals = map digitToInt
```

Comment: Can I give you an advice? The function readDecimals returns error when the string doesn't contain decimals. It is best practice in Haskell to annotate the return type to reflect this `readDecimals s = if all isDigit s then Just (map digitToInt s) else Nothing`

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

readDecimals :: String -> [Int]
readDecimals = unfoldr (listToMaybe . readNext)
  where readNext = reads :: ReadS Int
```

Note this will stop when it cannot read any more digits instead of throwing an exception.